# Class equation of subgroup of $SL(4,\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

> Can you point me toward a computation-light derivation of the class equation of the subgroup of $SL(4,\mathbb{F}_2)$ consisting of upper-triangular matrices with 1's on the main diagonal?

The question is motivated by a homework problem from a class in representation theory. The homework problem is to describe all the irreducible complex representations of the above group. I began by doing pages of calculations in the group, trying to find the conjugacy classes by hand, so I would know how many representations to expect and might be able to play with the numbers to find their dimensions. I turned away from this because it was getting too computationally heavy for me to feel safe I wasn't making any small mistakes. I've started looking for representations in an ad-hoc way, but I don't know how many to expect or what dimensions, so this is also pretty hairy. Also, I'd like to organize my results using the character table, but for this again I would need to know the group's decomposition into conjugacy classes.

Besides specific computations, here is what I have figured out about the group: it is a semidirect product of $D_4$ and $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. This is because it acts on vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ with last component 0. The action coincides with the action of the upper left $3\times 3$ block on $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, so this gives us a homomorphism onto the subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb{F}_2)$ of upper-triangular matrices with 1's on the main diagonal. This latter group is isomorphic to $D_4$, and the restriction of the homomorphism to the subgroup of the original group which is 0 off the diagonal in the last column is an isomorphism. The kernel is the subgroup of matrices that are zero off the main diagonal *away* from the last column, and this is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. However I am unsure how to use this information to find the class equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculations should become simpler if you consider the semidirect product
$$G := \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & * & * & *\\
  & 1 & * & *\\
  &   & 1 & *\\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &   & * & *\\
  & 1 & * & *\\
  &   & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right)\rtimes \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & * &   &  \\
  & 1 &   &  \\
  &   & 1 & *\\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right) =: N\rtimes H.$$

Both $N$ and $H$ are elementary abelian, and you have mostly to understand the conjugation action of the three nonzero elements of $H$ on $N$.

---

**EDIT:** As you finished your assignment I now post an almost complete solution.

Denoting the elements of $H$ as $1, x, y$ and $z$ we get:
$$x^{-1}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b & a \\
d & c 
\end{array}\right)\cdot x := \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 &   &  \\
  & 1 &   &  \\
  &   & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &   & b & a\\
  & 1 & d & c\\
  &   & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 &   &  \\
  & 1 &   &  \\
  &   & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 &   & b+d & a+c\\
  & 1 & d & c\\
  &   & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
b+d & a+c\\
d & c 
\end{array}\right)$$

and (only in short notation) 
$y^{-1}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b & a \\
d & c 
\end{array}\right)\cdot y = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
b & a+b\\
d & c+d 
\end{array}\right)$

$N$ being normal and $H$ being abelian, the conjugacy classes are contained in the cosets $hN$ for $h \in H$. As $N$ is abelian, one can determine the centralizers of the elements of $N$ by looking at the action of $x$ and $y$ on $N$. One obtains that $N$ contributes $2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 4$ to the class equation of $G$.

Now consider the centralizers/conjugacy classes of $X := \langle x, N\rangle$: $N$ is abelian and has index $2$ in $X$. By the action of $x$ on $N$ is $C := \left(\begin{array}{cc}
* & *\\
0 & 0 
\end{array}\right) = \mathrm{Z}(X)$ the center of $X$, and $xC$ is the conjugacy class of $x$ in $X$. As $N$ is abelian, the elements $t$ of $X\setminus N$ all have centralizers in $X$ of order $4$ and their conjugacy classes (in $X$) are the cosets $tC$.

As $X$ has index $2$ in $G$ (i.e., is normal of prime index), for elements $t \in X\setminus N$ either the centralizer grows by factor $2$ or its conjugacy class is merged with another conjugacy class.

As the centralizer of $y$ in $G$ is $\langle x, \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & *\\
0 & * 
\end{array}\right)\rangle$, there are two conjugacy classes (of $G$) of order $4$ contained in $xN$ ("growing centralizer"). As $y^{-1}\cdot x\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0 
\end{array}\right)\cdot y = x\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 1 
\end{array}\right)$ the other two conjugacy classes merge to a conjugacy class of $G$ of order $8$ contained in $xN$. Hence, $xN$ contributes $2\cdot 4 + 8$ to the class equation of $G$.

By symmetry, i.e., using automorphisms of $G$ fixing $N$ that map $x$ to $y$ (easy) rsp. $x$ to $z$ (not too difficult), $yN$ and $zN$ contribute the same as $xN$ does to the class equation, which is
$$ G = 2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 4 + 3\cdot[2\cdot 4 + 8],$$
as Ben already commented.

*Extra credit*: Find the class equation for $\mathbb{F}_2$ generalized to any finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

(Hint: Conjugate with diagonal matrices)

---

**EDIT 2:** The action of the element $x$ on $N$ has a two-dimensional centralizer $C_N(x)$ (viewing the elementary abelian group as $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space) that equals the commutator $[x, N]$. The same holds for $y$ and $z$, and the centralizers of any pair intersect one-dimensionally. As $N$ is elementary abelian, one can find an automorphism of $G$ exchanging $x$ and $z$ and fixing $N$ (*not* pointwise, but as a set):

One automorphism exchanging $x$ and $z$ maps a basis of $N$ like this:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)\mapsto
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\mapsto
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$, whereas $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ are fixed.

Comment: Additional hint: If two elements are conjugated in $G$, they are also conjugated mod $N$, which is abelian... ($N$ for example contributes $2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 4$ to the class equation of $G$ as you easily deduce using the action of $H$ on $N$).

Comment: +1 This is all very helpful.  You are saying that every conjugacy class is contained in a coset of $N$...

Comment: Using your hint I am getting $64=2\cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 2 + 2\cdot 4 + 3\cdot [2\cdot 4 + 8]$ as the class equation, do you agree? (Here I have organized the class equation into cosets of $N$.)

Comment: Hmmm... I am skeptical of your claim about there being an automorphism of $G$ fixing $N$ that maps $x$ to $z$. According to purely numerical considerations, there should be 2 faithful 4-dimensional irreducible representations of $G$. Since $x,y,z$ are not conjugate in $G$, any automorphisms sending $x$ to $y$ or $z$ should be outer. But if they exist, then $|Aut(G)|\geq 3$, thus (by composing one representation with the automorphisms) there should be at least 3 irreducible 4-dimensional representations of $G$. Or are some of the representations obtained this way conjugate to each other?

Comment: ... With more careful examination I found that the 4-dimensional representations are fixed (up to equivalence) by composition with these automorphisms, so that answers my doubt...